# Headers: get email name/address

Tags: c#, mailkit, mimekit

Scenario is that I am replying to an original email message.

I am populating a new message to send with the required elements of the original message (the original body, reciepient, sender, the reply, etc.)

In my code, var headers is a collection the original email's headers.

newMessage is a new MimeMessage.

Here is what the value of headers[HeaderId.ReplyTo] is. (From the original email's headers.):

```
     "\"Sam Taylor\" <emailUser3@testEmailServer.com>"
```

So here is what I do to populate the new email message TO:

newMessage.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(headers[HeaderId.ReplyTo], "emailUser3"))

What is bugging me: I cannot get away from using the literal value "emailUser3"

How can I find that value "emailUser3" in the headers so I can use that to replace the literal string?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, The Reply-To header contains a *list* of addresses (which in your case is only a single address).

Second, you need to parse the header value - not just use the whole value as the "Name" property of a new MailboxAddress.

Here's how to do it:

```
var replyToValue = headers[HeaderId.ReplyTo];
var replyToAddresses = InternetAddressList.Parse (replyToValue);

newMessage.To.AddRange (replyToAddresses);
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up before seeing your answer parsing and extracting out the part I want with using replace and Regex. So I'm not far off from what you suggest. I will take a look at your code! Thanks!

Comment: And here is exactly how I did it:   

//Regex eval to get the inbox names (ex. "emailUser3", "emailUser4"

string emailBoxNameReplyTo = Regex.Replace(headers[HeaderId.ReplyTo], @"^.*? <", "");

emailBoxNameReplyTo = Regex.Replace(emailBoxNameReplyTo, @"@.*$", "");

string emailBoxNameFrom = Regex.Replace(headers[HeaderId.To], @"^.*? <", "");

//Assign the new "To" and "From" to MailboxAddress

newMessage.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(headers[HeaderId.ReplyTo], emailBoxNameReplyTo));

newMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(headers[HeaderId.To], emailBoxNameFrom));

Comment: Ok. What you advising is working for the mailbox; however, I still need to parse out the "emailUser3" for this part later on when I attempt to send the reply: client.Authenticate(emailBoxNameFrom, "Aries.");

Comment: Specifically:Ok. What you advising is working for the mailbox; however, I still need to parse out the "emailBoxNameReplier" for this part later on when I attempt to send the reply: 

 string emailBoxNameReplier = Regex.Replace(headers[HeaderId.To], @"^.*? <", "");

            emailBoxNameReplier = Regex.Replace(emailBoxNameReplier, @"@.*$", "");

client.Authenticate(emailBoxNameReplier, PASSWORD);//emailBoxNameReplier = "emailUser4"

Will use what you recommend to populate the mailboxes and will use my regex to get the mailbox name for the authentication.